# Move SKSpriteNode in direction it's facing (Swift)

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

If I have a sprite node that is being rotated, if I stop it at a random point during the rotation, how can I then make it go forward in the direction it's facing?

Comment: This may be what you're looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25628811/spritekit-move-rotated-physicsbody-with-applyimpulse